# Magento 2 stock update returns 0

Tags: magento2, stock

Im trying to update the stock of my products programmatically, using this code:

```
$stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
$this->logger->info($stockItem->getQty())
```

$stockItem->getQty() logs the right qty amount, however all stock in backend is updated to 0 when I run this loop. Anyone have an idea how this is possible?

Comment: If you do for 1 product still it shows 0 in backend?

Comment: @KeyurShah Good find! Updating only one product gives the expected result. What could cause this?

Comment: It means that you are using singleton of the object , you need to create a new object every time to avoid this situation @Digitaq

Comment: It is possible for you to share full code? @Digitaq

Comment: @KeyurShah I was able to fix the problem! It wasnt that I was using singleton of the object, but the list with stock quanitites that got sent to me got corrupted with false data. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$stockItem->setQty($qty);
$this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
 $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
$this->logger->info($stockItem->getQty())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
protected $stockRegistry;

public function __construct(StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry)
{
    $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
}

/**
* Set the quantity in stock for a product
*
*/
public function applyNewQty($sku, $newQty)
{
    $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $origQty = $stockItem->getQty();
    $difference = $newQty - $origQty;
    $stockItem->setQtyCorrection($difference);
    $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);

    // note that at this point, $stockItem->getQty() is incorrect, so you'll need to reload if you need that value
}
```